# When do we use FIX50sp2 and FIXT11.xml?

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am newbie to quickfix, bit confused between quickfix versions FIX50sp2 and FIXT11.

When to use what?
Also i got to know to use FIXT11.xml when using FIX 50sp2 version, why not FIX50SP2.xml ?

I am trying to add a group `TrdInstrmtLegGrp` to my FIXT11.xml, rebuild the jar,  earlier I was using `quickfixj-messages-fix50sp2-2.0.0` jar but now after doing changes to `FIXT11.xml` and adding jar `quickfixj-messages-fixt11-2.1.0-SNAPSHOT` it gives error on `TradeCaptureReport`:

`20180418-04:46:29: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    quickfix/fixt11/TradeCaptureReport$NoLegs.get(Lquickfix/field/LegSide;)Lquickfix/field/LegSide; @2: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'quickfix/field/LegSide' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'quickfix/StringField'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @2
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'quickfix/fixt11/TradeCaptureReport$NoLegs', 'quickfix/field/LegSide' }
    stack: { 'quickfix/fixt11/TradeCaptureReport$NoLegs', 'quickfix/field/LegSide' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b600 0457 2bb0`

This is how my FIXT11.xml looks as for this group in similar order of my API:

```
<component name='InstrmtLegGrp'>
  <group name='NoLegs' required='N'>
    <field name='LegSymbol' required='N'/>
    <field name='LegSecurityID' required='N'/>
    <field name='LegSecurityIdSource1' required='N'/>
    <field name='LegSecurityDesc' required='N'/>
    <field name='LegRatioQty' required='N'/>
    <field name='LegSide' required='N'/>
  </group>
</component>
```

Or do I need to do the required group changes in FIX50sp2.xml?

Answer (score 1):

From FIX 5.0 onwards, Quickfixj introduces the concept of transport dictionary and app dictionary. 
Transport dictionary will contain all transport related admin messages as Heartbeat/Logon/Logoff etc. whereas Appdictionary will contain the business messages as Quote request, trade capture etc.

You can check the QuickfixJ configuration TransportDataDictionary & AppDataDictionary.(https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.4/usage/configuration.html)

Comment: Thanks Hemant for the info. this really cleared half of my question.